# Difference between response and last_response in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have a test that checks if the requested page returns a 200 status code:

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
```

However, if I explicitly return a different status code using the following the test:

```
return render json: { error: 'error message' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

it still passes.

Why do `response` and `last_response` have different statuses:

```
response.status      # 200
last_response.status # 422
```

Answer (score 8):

`response` is provided by `ActionController::TestCase`.

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html):

> An ActionDispatch::TestResponse object, representing the response of the last HTTP response.

For reference, [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) are the rspec docs for controller tests. This may help clear up how `response` is supposed to be used.

---

`last_response` comes from `Rack::MockResponse < Rack::Response`

From the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/MockSession#last_response-instance_method):

> Return the last response received in the session. Raises an error if no requests have been sent yet.

---

In your test case, you probably used a method that allows you to mock visiting a page. This will set your `response.status` to `200` as you've had a successful request. If you then use Rack to stimulate an endpoint, e.g.:

```
put '/users', {my_user: 'blah'}
```

and you do it with incorrect parameters, then your `last_response.status` will be `422`.

Ultimately, the confusion comes down the similarity of naming between `ActionController` and `Rack::MockResponse`, which I agree is rather confusing.